# curly braces followed by event, what does that mean in javascript module?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I'm studying on javascript module. I came across this file which confuses me with the usage of curly braces and click event places after it. Though I can guess that it might mean,

> if the element (inside curly braces) clicked do this..

I would like to confirm it and know the reason it's binded this way.

```
$(document).on("click.es.reports.link", "[data-reports-link]", function(){

        var button = $(this);
        var props = "url,extension,uid,type,object,title,description".split(",");
        var data = {};

        $.each(props, function(i, prop){
            data[prop] = button.data(prop);
        });

        FunSocial.dialog({

            content: FunSocial.ajax("site/views/reports/confirmReport", {
                    title: data.title,
                    description: data.description
            }),
            selectors: {
                "{message}": "[data-reports-message]",
                "{reportButton}": "[data-report-button]",
                "{cancelButton}": "[data-cancel-button]"
            },
            bindings: {

                "{reportButton} click": function() {

                    ..code removed for brevity...
                },

                "{cancelButton} click": function() {
                    ..code removed for brevity...
                }       
            }   
        });
    });
```

from the code above,

what does this mean:

```
"{message}": "[data-reports-message]",
```

And what does this mean:

```
"{reportButton} click": function() {
    ..code removed for brevity...
    },
```

Comment: It's not a JavaScript or jQuery thing. Apparently `FunSocial.dialog` does something with those placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both

```
"{message}": "[data-reports-message]",
```

and

```
"{reportButton} click": function() {
    ..code removed for brevity...
    },
```

...are in object initializers; they create properties with exactly those names:

```js
var obj = {
  "{message}": "[data-reports-message]"
};
console.log(obj);
```

The `{}` parts look like placeholders that `FunSocial.dialog` does something with. For instance, in your second example:

```
"{reportButton} click": function() {
    ..code removed for brevity...
    },
```

...I suspect it takes that name, replaces `{reportButton}` with the necessary selector to identify the "report button," and then sets up an event handler on that button.